Can RedisShake be used as a data synchronization mechanism for MemoryDB?
Since AWS currently doesn't support cross-region data replication/sync across clusters, could RedisShake be used to replicate data?
I mean, i don't want to migrate data, instead i want to have high availability across 2 aws regions.
Currently I'm planning to use some queue SNS/SQS/EventBridge-like service along with lambda, but i think this would be more complex, due to data inconsistency.

Maybe RedisShake - Scan Reader can help you, but RedisShake is not designed to run indefinitely.
